# Change CUPS printer name

Tags: printing, rename, printers, cups

successfully installed my cups printer Ubuntu18.4. When i click the add printer icon in the device side it shows name as "CUPS-BRF-Printer".. I would like to change this name. How to change the default name.. How to change it?

Answer (score 6):

1º Stop CUPS Service

2º Edit /etc/cups/printers.conf and replace the old-name text with the new one. (appears only once)

3º Save the file and start the service

Comment: Could please add command how to stop cups service for systemd: `systemctl stop cups`

And what exactly need to be changed? I have `br` name, there is a lot of entries for `br`...

It's <Printer> tag attribute. Thanks anyway...

Comment: Also you could add allowed chars for printer name: CUPS allows printer names to contain any printable character except SPACE, TAB, "/", and "#". Also, printer and class names are not case-sensitive

Answer (score 0):

```
systemctl stop cups.service
nano /etc/cups/printers.conf # change the name of a printer in question
mv /etc/cups/ppd/old_printer_name.ppd /etc/cups/ppd/new_printer_name.ppd # rename the ppd
systemctl start cups.service
```

source: the answer by FOP, commands were added